# Laravel missing index file

Tags: php, laravel

A Laravel app works fine [here](http://demos.maxoffsky.com/facebook-login/). Its code is placed on [Github](https://github.com/msurguy/laravel-facebook-login). When I place it on [my server](http://www.crushwallet.com), it is missing the index file. Please guide me what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: What error does it throws ?

Comment: It doesn't show any error.

Comment: Then what's the problem in it  ? :)

Comment: Missing the `index` means ?

Comment: When I open http://www.crushwallet.com nothing shows up.

Comment: Well I would include the index.php as part of the git project, obviously it is not currently part of the git project

Answer (score 1):

You need to move all the files one directory level back, so that public is your web root. See http://www.crushwallet.com/public/index.php your index is there, just not in the right place.

Comment: Thanks. How do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Looked at the git repo and noticed the public directory, so took a guess and stuck public on the end of the URL. The errors show there is some PHP running there.